# Will every Camel Context have a separate Threadpool by default?

Tags: apache-camel

I've read the https://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html document. It is not clear to me however whether a given route in one camel context uses a separate threadpool from a totally separate route in another camel context. Basically what I need to establish is whether by default multiple camel contexts you create, will use the/a same threadpool. Did I miss soemthing in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

No each thread-pool is private to each camel context. Unless you explicit setup a shared thread-pool and refer to use that pool in those Camel's. But a general rule of thumb, its all isolated per camel context.

Comment: Thanks for this. One follow-up then: how do I reference a shared thread-pool from a camel context?

Comment: You can refer to it by the id of the thread pool which is then looked up in the registry, such as spring beans, cdi etc. The CiA2 book covers this in the concurrency chapter.